# Extract All Data from Source Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to extra data from multiple .xlsm in a folder from a specific cell. The idea is to take a folder that has multiple .xlsm files and extract a specific cell into my current workbook.

See code.

```
Option Explicit


Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\Users\maxd\OneDrive - Nortek, Inc\Coil Test Data\coils_35_and_36\36\WET\Testing\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH


Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   rowTarget = 7

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   'On Error GoTo errHandler
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'set up the target worksheet
   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Sheet1")

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xlsm*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Summary")


      'import the data
      With wsTarget
         .Range("I" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("B25").Value


         'optional source filename in the last column
         .Range("N" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
      End With

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub




Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Actual Results = it does nothing as if there is not a file in the folder.

Expected Results = It will pull the data from cell B25 and insert it to I7 of my current worksheet.

EDIT: When I F8 through the code, it gets to "Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Summary")" Then I get a runtime error 91

Comment: If you step through (`F8`) are all the variables what you expect them to be? This doesn't look quite good `Set wsSource = wbSource.Summary` ... have you meant `Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Summary")` instead? Also if you comment out `On Error GoTo errHandler` it should quickly highlight where the problem is next time you run the macro.

Comment: I edited the code based on your comments. I am now getting a runtime error 91.

Comment: Do you have that sheet name in that workbook? My suggestion was based on the given code... Make sure the `Worksheets("Summary")` exists in your source workbooks. Assuming it was meant to be `"Sheet1"` there, and `Set wsTarget = Sheets("Summary")` instead.

Comment: So the sheet that I want to put the values into is named "Sheet1". The sheet that I am wanting to pull the data from is named "Summary".

Comment: I changed it to ```Set wsTarget = Sheets("Sheet1")``` and ```Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Summary")``` assuming that the target is where the data is going and the source if where it is pulled from. I still get runtime error 91 on that second bit there.

Comment: That runtime error probably means your workbook variable doesn't get set appropriatelly... `Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)`  (or so i think). Does the workbook open before you get the error? If you do `?wbSource.Name` in immediate window (after you get the error, before you END), you get anything?

Comment: No, the workbook does not open. I get runtime error 424 - "object required"

Comment: I can't see nothing else obviously wrong with the code to be honest. How about `?sFile` value at that time ? Does it get populated with what you expect? and... did the source workbook open prior the error?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works, I'm just having a different path obviously. Do you need to have that constant outside the sub? Try to put it inside and see if that makes any difference (who knows what weirdness might be lurking...).

Comment: @DakotaWMaxwell, have you confirmed the sheet and workbook exist?

Comment: I will try to capture the comments here... The workbook does open when running the code. This means that it does in fact reach out to grab the data. Once the workbook opens, I get "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". This is right at ```Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")``` - Is Sheet1 supposed to be in the file that the code reaches out to?

Comment: Got it to work!!!! Thanks guys!!!

Comment: By the way, the problem was that I had one of the .xlsm files open. Excel will not let you open two files with the same name.